# Query finds no values when sharppend

Tags: mysql, query, subquery, greatest-n-per-group

I am trying to join two datasets and find the most recent certification date

I the following 2 datasets

Certifications

- (1, 'Judge Level 1', 'Judge', 10, 2),
- (2, 'Judge Level 2', 'Judge', 20, 2),
- (3, 'Judge Level 3', 'judge', 30, 2),
- (4, 'Olympic Judge', 'olympic judge', 30, 2),
- (5, 'Junior Leader', 'leadership', 10, 1),
- (6, 'Trainee', 'leadership', 10, 1),
- (7, 'Instructor', 'leadership', 10, 1);

members_certifications

- (1000052, 7, '2016-07-01'),
- (1000053, 1, '2016-07-01'),
- (1000053, 3, '2018-07-01'),
- (1000053, 4, '2019-07-01'),
- (1000053, 5, '2020-07-01'),
- (1000059, 1, '2016-07-01'),
- (1000059, 2, '2017-07-01'),
- (1000059, 5, '2016-07-04'),
- (1000059, 6, '2016-07-01'),
- (1000059, 6, '2016-07-02');

I would like the result set to be

- 1000059, Junior Leader , leadership, 10, 2016-09-04
- 1000059, Judge,Judge Level 2, 20, 2016-09-04

I created a exact example http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/20c30b1/3/1  MySql version 5.6

The first query produces a large data set when I reduce the query by setting a specific id (in this case 100059) I get 0 results.

Also is there a more query efficient or less bulky way create this query.

```
CREATE TABLE `certifications` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(254) NOT NULL,
  `type` varchar(254) NOT NULL,
  `sort_order` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `expiration_interval` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '2'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


CREATE TABLE `members_certifications` (
  `member_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `certification_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `effective_date` date NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Query 1

```
SELECT members_certifications.member_id AS member_id,certifications.title AS title,
certifications.type AS type,certifications.sort_order AS sort_order,
MaxTable.effective_date AS effective_date FROM members_certifications, certifications,
(SELECT     members_certifications.member_id AS member_id,     certifications.type AS type,
 MAX(members_certifications.effective_date) AS effective_date   
 FROM     members_certifications, certifications  
 WHERE     members_certifications.certification_id = certifications.id   
 GROUP BY      certifications.type,members_certifications.member_id   ) MaxTable 
 WHERE  members_certifications.certification_id = certifications.id
 AND certifications.type = MaxTable.type  AND members_certifications.member_id = MaxTable.member_id  AND members_certifications.effective_date = MaxTable.effective_date 
ORDER BY  MaxTable.member_id, certifications.sort_order, MaxTable.type, certifications.title;
```

query II (0 results)

```
SELECT members_certifications.member_id AS member_id,certifications.title AS title,certifications.type AS type,certifications.sort_order AS sort_order,MaxTable.effective_date AS effective_date FROM members_certifications, certifications,  (SELECT     members_certifications.member_id AS member_id,     certifications.type AS type,     MAX(members_certifications.effective_date) AS effective_date   FROM     members_certifications, certifications   WHERE     members_certifications.certification_id = certifications.id   GROUP BY      certifications.type,members_certifications.member_id   ) MaxTable WHERE  members_certifications.certification_id = certifications.id  AND members_certifications.member_id = 100059  AND certifications.type = MaxTable.type  AND members_certifications.member_id = MaxTable.member_id  AND members_certifications.effective_date = MaxTable.effective_date ORDER BY  MaxTable.member_id, certifications.sort_order, MaxTable.type, certifications.title ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you are asking, but I would suggest that you use aliases and ANSI joins for your queries:

```
SELECT mc1.member_id AS member_id
      ,c1.title AS title
      ,c1.type AS type
      ,c1.sort_order AS sort_order
      ,MaxTable.effective_date AS effective_date 
FROM members_certifications mc1
JOIN certifications c1
    ON mc1.certification_id = c1.id
JOIN (SELECT mc2.member_id AS member_id
           , c2.type AS type
           , MAX(mc2.effective_date) AS effective_date   
      FROM members_certifications mc2
         , certifications c2 
      WHERE mc2.certification_id = c2.id   
      GROUP BY c2.type, mc2.member_id   
     ) MaxTable 
    ON c1.type = MaxTable.type  
   AND mc1.member_id = MaxTable.member_id  
   AND mc1.effective_date = MaxTable.effective_date 
ORDER BY  MaxTable.member_id, c1.sort_order, MaxTable.type, c1.title;
```

Regarding your second query in the fiddle, there is a slight difference between:

```
1000059 and 100059
```

So if you change that to:

```
SELECT mc1.member_id AS member_id
      ,c1.title AS title
      ,c1.type AS type
      ,c1.sort_order AS sort_order
      ,MaxTable.effective_date AS effective_date 
FROM members_certifications mc1
JOIN certifications c1
    ON mc1.certification_id = c1.id
JOIN (SELECT mc2.member_id AS member_id
           , c2.type AS type
           , MAX(mc2.effective_date) AS effective_date   
      FROM members_certifications mc2
         , certifications c2 
      WHERE mc2.certification_id = c2.id   
      GROUP BY c2.type, mc2.member_id   
     ) MaxTable 
    ON c1.type = MaxTable.type  
   AND mc1.member_id = MaxTable.member_id  
   AND mc1.effective_date = MaxTable.effective_date 
WHERE mc1.member_id = 1000059   
ORDER BY  MaxTable.member_id, c1.sort_order, MaxTable.type, c1.title;
```

does that give you the expected answer?

MySQL 8+ supports window functions which are far more efficient. Instead of doing a join against a sub-select you can use a window function to determine max_effective_date, and then filter with that:

```
SELECT member_id, title, type, sort_order, effective_date
FROM (
    SELECT mc1.member_id AS member_id
          ,c1.title AS title
          ,c1.type AS type
          ,c1.sort_order AS sort_order
          ,mc1.effective_date  
          ,Max(effective_date) over (partition by member_id, c2.type) AS max_effective_date 
   FROM members_certifications mc1
   JOIN certifications c1
        ON mc1.certification_id = c1.id
) AS T
WHERE max_effective_date = effective_date 
ORDER BY member_id, sort_order, type, title;
```

Comment: Tthe change of the member_id gave the expected data, Will the ansi joins work like LEFT JOINS such that if there is no data null shows up?

Comment: No, join is the same as inner join. If you want an left outer join, use left join or left outer join.